# captured and displayed image on imageView, now i want to pass the imageView to another activity

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, kotlin, android-bitmap, kotlin-extension

This is my code on android studio using kotlin to capture and show image on main activity, I want that captured image to be displayed on my other activity. After image has been captured, the image will be displayed on the imageView on main Activity, now i want to pass that image to another activity using buttonClassify

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initializeTensorClassifier()
    buttonRecognize.setOnClickListener {
        setVisibilityOnCaptured(false)
        cameraView.captureImage {
            onImageCaptured(it)
        }
     buttonClassify.setOnClickListener{
         val intent = Intent(this, classify::class.java)

         startActivity(intent)
     }
    }
}

private fun onImageCaptured(it: CameraKitImage) {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(it.bitmap, INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT, false)
    showCapturedImage(bitmap)

    classifier?.let {
        try {
            showRecognizedResult(it.recognizeImage(bitmap))
        } catch (e: java.lang.RuntimeException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Crashing due to classification.closed() before the recognizer finishes!")
        }
    }
}



private fun showCapturedImage(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
    runOnUiThread {
        imageCaptured.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        imageCaptured.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the image in a file, you can just pass the path to the file. If not, you can pass the `Bitmap` as a `Parcelable` in the `Intent` Extras.

```
private fun showCapturedImage(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
    runOnUiThread {
        imageCaptured.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        imageCaptured.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

        val nextActivityIntent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("captured_image", bitmap)
        }

        startActivity(nextActivityIntent)
    }
}
```

Then in the next Activity you could retreive it like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstance: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val capturedImage = intent.extras.getParcelable("captured_image") as Bitmap?
    /* Use bitmap as you wish */
}
```

Beware, large bitmaps can throw **Exceptions** when trying to be passed as Intent Extras, so consider saving the image and passing around the path.